# Озвучить текст из TextView

Tags: java, android

Возможно ли озвучить текст который отображается в `TextView`?

Может встроенным синтезатором речи Android или как-то по-другому? В какую сторону копать?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Да, возможно, например с помощью встроенного синтезатора речи.

Вот простой пример использования `TextToSpeech`:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements TextToSpeech.OnInitListener {
    private Button mSpeakButton;

    private TextToSpeech mTextToSpeech;
    private boolean mIsInit;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mSpeakButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.speek_button);
        mTextToSpeech = new TextToSpeech(this, this);
        mSpeakButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (mIsInit) {
                    String textToSpeech = "Привет!";
                    mTextToSpeech.speak(textToSpeech, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null, "id1");
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onInit(int status) {
        if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
            Locale locale = new Locale("ru");
            int result = mTextToSpeech.setLanguage(locale);
            if (result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA || result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED) {
                mIsInit = false;
            } else {
                mIsInit = true;
            }
        } else {
            mIsInit = false;
        }
    }
}
```

При запуске приложения происходит инициализация `TextToSpeech`, результат которой возвращается в коллбэк:

```
public void onInit(int status)
```

Если инициализация прошла успешно, то флаг `mIsInit` устанавливается в `true`, в противном случае – в `false`.

Далее, по нажатию на кнопку происходит воспроизведение текста из переменной `textToSpeech`.

Comment: Спасибо буду пробовать.

Comment: Для метода speak из строки mTextToSpeech.speak(textToSpeech, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null, "id1");  выходит такое предупреждение или ошибка.

Call requires API level 21 (current min is 15): android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech#speak

Comment: Но на android 6 работает, возможности проверить на более старых версиях нету. Скажите это не критичная ошибка?

Comment: @Gadzhi, Для API level < 21 нужно использовать метод `int speak (String text, int queueMode, HashMap<String, String> params)`, для API level >= 21 – метод `int speak (CharSequence text, int queueMode, Bundle params, String utteranceId)`.

Comment: Понял. Спасибо.

Comment: Я извиняюсь. А что нужно передавать в HashMap для версий Api <21?

Comment: @Gadzhi, [Список параметров](http://bit.ly/2gsM4j3).

Comment: т.е. для api < 21 должно быть так  mTextToSpeech.speak(textToSpeech, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);  ?

Comment: @Gadzhi, Если Вы не хотите задавать какие-либо параметры, то можете передать просто `null`.

Comment: думаю что разобрался. спасибо.