# Озвучка текста из строки (Java)

Tags: java, android

Каким образом можно реализовать озвучку строки (из того же NetBeans под Windows,не под Android!) при помощи встроенного синтезатора речи Android.

Видел тему [Озвучить текст из TextView](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/601741/%D0%9E%D0%B7%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82-%D0%B8%D0%B7-textview)

Не получилось разобраться.

Суть в том,что необходимо ввести в самом коде строку,а Text-To-Speech озвучит его.

Подключил библиотеку Android.jar - безуспешно. http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/a/Downloadandroidjar.htm

Нужна ваша помощь.

Точка входа :

```
//реализован интерфейс с полем ввода и кнопкой без листенера.

package First;

import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public abstract class Main implements TextToSpeech.OnInitListener {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Hello");
        frame.setSize(400, 400);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        FlowLayout fl = new FlowLayout();
        frame.setLayout(fl);

        JButton button = new JButton("Test");
        button.setSize(120, 120);
        String s = "Hello";
        JTextField tf1;
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();

        tf1 = new JTextField(20);
        frame.add(panel);
        panel.add(tf1);
        panel.add(button);
    }
 }
```

**Класс с говорилкой:**

```
package First;

import java.util.Locale;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class AndroidTextToSpeechActivity extends Activity implements
        TextToSpeech.OnInitListener {

/**
 * Called when the activity is first created.
 */

    private TextToSpeech tts;
    private Button btnSpeak;
    private EditText txtText;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        tts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);

        btnSpeak = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSpeak);

        txtText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtText);

        // button on click event
        btnSpeak.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                speakOut();
            }

        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        // Don't forget to shutdown tts!
        if (tts != null) {
            tts.stop();
            tts.shutdown();
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onInit(int status) {

        if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {

            int result = tts.setLanguage(Locale.US);

            if (result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA
                    || result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED) {
                Log.e("TTS", "This Language is not supported");
            } else {
                btnSpeak.setEnabled(true);
                speakOut();
            }

        } else {
            Log.e("TTS", "Initilization Failed!");
        }

    }

    private void speakOut() {

        String text = txtText.getText().toString();

        tts.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
    }
}
```

т.е. использовать библиотеку Android.jar чтобы в Windows в IDE NetBeans реализовать говорилку.

В сети до меня не использовали библиотеку Android.jar под Windows,так что документации нет.

По сути это библиотека содержащая доступ ко всем методом и функциям ядра Android.

Да,это что-то вроде ядра.

Comment: "Не получилось разобраться" не есть описание проблемы. Надо разбираться с API не по примерам кода, а по документации. RTFM здесь: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.html

Comment: Не понятно, откуда возникла идея, что импорт Android.jar в проект java под Windows позволит выполнять те же операции, что и на платформе Android - есть еще нативный слой, выше которого стоят платформозависимые механизмы вроде механизма широковещательных сообщений

Comment: @0xFFh я подумал,а почему бы нет? разве не будет работать не большая функция Text-To-Speech,которая реализована даже в браузере Google Chrome. Изначальная идея вообще лежала найти библиотеку Text-To-Speech для Java,но увы такой нет,только Mbrola,в которой русский язык не поддерживается. Потому я сюда и пришел,чтобы подробно обсудить это.

Comment: Зачем вы минусуете сообщение,если не можете дать чёткий ответ?
Это что-то вроде "я не понял,это не работает,так что минус" если вы не разбираетесь,так не минусуйте, эту тему нужно добить до конца,а не просто минусы ставить.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Возможно, вы не смогли осознать, что он асинхронный. То есть после создания экземпляра [TextToSpeach](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.html), сразу отправлять текст на говорение нельзя: нужно дождаться окончания инициализации (информация приходит в лиснер, которые передается [конструктору](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.html#TextToSpeech(android.content.Context,%20android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.OnInitListener))), [установить](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.html#setLanguage(java.util.Locale)) язык и проверить его [доступность](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.html#LANG_AVAILABLE), и только потом что-то [говорить](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.html#speak(java.lang.CharSequence,%20int,%20android.os.Bundle,%20java.lang.String)).

На некоторых устройствах TTS вообще изначально не установлен, и пользователю будет предложено выкачать и поставить соответствующий модуль. Соответственно, синтеза  до этого не будет.

Comment: и как же это будет выглядеть в коде?Просто я пишу не под тесты для Android,а под тесты на  Windows,используя библиотеку Android.jar
Хорошо,допустим необходимо дождаться окончания инициализации. А дальше как сделать? Я по той теме,на которую ссылку дал попробовал создать GUI с полем ввода и кнопкой. Ничего не работает. Потому и ищу помощи здесь хотя бы.

Comment: Примеров кода вагон, спросите гугла. http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-text-to-speech-tutorial/

Comment: за пример спасибо. А реально ли привязать его к строке? Т.е. дождаться инициализации,а после он брал строку и говорил её? Мне именно это нужно.

Comment: даже в примере там нужно создавать проект Android и тестируется это под Android,а не под Windows. Моя же затея воплотить это всё в Windows...Используя библиотеку Android.jar

Comment: Опишите в вопросе тогда среду, в которой вы все это пробуете. Я про widows и android.jar ничего не знаю. У вас более простые эксперименты проходили? Интерфейс с одной кнопкой создать можете?

Comment: отредактировал вопрос,посмотрите.
сейчас по поводу интерфейса с одной кнопкой и тем же полем ввода напишу.

Comment: Вы добавили ссылку на неясное. Покажите документацию на этот Android.jar или статью-пример, как его используют под Windows.

Comment: добавил информацию.